# Trying to connect Oracle 10g to execute a query but getting some errors

Tags: java, oracle

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
//step1 load the driver class  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","scott","tiger");  

//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

//step4 execute query  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

//step5 close the connection object  
con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

and the error is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I'm unaware of connecting to localhost.

Comment: Please do a little research on SO before posting a question.  This has been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in your JDBC driver class registration.
Make sure you have [driver-jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) included in your library. You can also refer [this](http://www.javaonlinelessons.com/jdbc/connect-oracle-database-with-oracle-jdbc-driver)